# `error: Failed to create repository /demo due to: POST https://api.github.com/user/repos: 404 Not Found []`

Tags: git, github, kubernetes, minikube, jenkins-x

I have setup kubernetes cluster using minikube on local , installed jenkins x on that but while creating project on jx using **jx create spring** I am getting error `error: Failed to create repository /demo5 due to: POST https://api.github.com/user/repos: 404 Not Found []`
I have also tried with **jx create spring --git-username=user_name --git-api-token=token**

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, although the URL for me is `https://api.github.com/orgs/XXX/repos`.

Comment: In my case the account wasn't an organization.

Comment: Harold L. Brown, How did you resolve that. Can you please help me.

Comment: you need to create an organisation in your git account.

Comment: Yes, I have created an organization but while creating application using `jx create spring` it is showing error `error: Failed to create repository sarika/demo due to: POST https://api.github.com/orgs/sarika/repos: 403 You need admin access to the organization before adding a repository to it. []`. I have added admin access to member also.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue while running through the getting started guide for https://toolkit.fluxcd.io/get-started/. I ran into this issue while trying to create a repo from a token that I had created. Turns out I not given the token that I was using for the guide enough permissions to be able to create a repo.

Try checking the permissions of the token. That immediately resolved the issue for me.

I think Github responds with a poor response code choice in this case. Should be an unauthorised response.

Answer (score 0):

was the user_name you supplied a valid github user name? btw the repository name you gave was it just `demo5` or did you add a `/` at the beginning? Maybe we need to strip out any leading/trailing slash characters

Comment: yes, the user_name supplied is the valid github user name. The repository name that I gave is `demo5`. I have not added `/` this character.